# Duplicate data using a partition query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written the following partition query in order to show a rolling sum for customer orders over the years, but am getting duplicate records and am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
SELECT
    sc.Cust_no,
    YEAR(sc.invoice_date),
    SUM([SQFT]) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY sc.Cust_no, YEAR(sc.invoice_date) 
        ORDER BY YEAR(sc.invoice_date)
     ) as Rolling_Sum
FROM ns.SAR_Combined sc
GROUP BY
    Cust_no,
    sqft,
    YEAR(sc.invoice_date)
```

What the output looks like

```
Cust_no Year    Sqft
0001    2015    10806.15
0001    2015    10806.15
0001    2015    10806.15
0001    2015    10806.15
0002    2013    26520
0002    2013    26520
0002    2013    26520
0002    2013    26520
0002    2013    26520
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want a cumulative sum.  If so, you need to use a window function on the aggregation:

```
Select sc.Cust_no, year(sc.invoice_date),
       sum(Sum([SQFT])) over (partition by sc.Cust_no, year(sc.invoice_date)
                              order by year(sc.invoice_date)
                             ) as Rolling_Sum
from ns.SAR_Combined sc
group by Cust_no, year(sc.invoice_date);
```

The reason you are getting "duplication" is due to `sqft` in the `group by` clause.  However, simply removing it won't fix your problem -- need to change the calculation of `Rolling_Sum` as well.